# Highcharts/Highstock : Auto scroll on the graph with overflow-x, instead of a scrollbar

Tags: css, highcharts

Having set min to display only 6 bars.
Enabling scrollbar will give me the scrollbar, But I want to have the auto scroll on the graph with overflow-x: scroll.
Without having scrollbar, can I get the scroll working on swiping on the graph in mobile devices.

Can any one please help me on this.

`Please find jsfiddle for your reference.
http://jsfiddle.net/2obuvn1e/1/`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Ruth

Comment: Put the container in the wrapper div with overflow-x scroll property. http://jsfiddle.net/2obuvn1e/3/

Comment: Hello morganfree, 
Looking for the same scroll functionality as highstock provide, not as a scrollbar, but on the graph.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same functionality without the scrollbar can be achieved with [Chart.panning](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.panning).

```
chart: {
        type: 'column',
        marginLeft: 150,
        panning: true
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2obuvn1e/4/

Additional options which you can consider is [Chart.panKey](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.panKey) and for mobiles devices [followTouchMove.](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.followTouchMove)